# iOS - Get the "real" height of a letter

Tags: ios, uifont

I am trying to layout text on a UIView.

(The yellow area is the frame of the UILabel with a background color).

When I use sizeWithFont I get this, which  has a very large space above the letter:

[image: p with sizeWithFont]

When I use `font.pointSize` i get this for "i" which is good-

[image: p with font.pointSize]

**BUT**
When i use it for "p" I get the precise height but the letter is drawn in the bottom and cropped.

[image: p with font.pointSize]

**How can i get get the glyph only centered in the frame ? **

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a lot of properties on [`UIFont`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to help in this situation:

- `pointSize`
- `ascender`
- `descender`
- `capHeight`
- `xHeight`
- `lineHeight`

Comment: It would be nice to have a picture so it is obvious what they all are defined as. For instance, does pointSize == ascender + descender and is ascender >= capHeight?

Comment: @Matt, it's an oldy, but I find the image on https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/ very helpful.

Comment: these font properties often lie - not sure if it’s iOS or the fonts themselves - i’m looking at a font now, where the lineHeight is identical to pointSize (very odd), and ascender - descender + leading is about 10% less than required bounding box to enclose the whole word.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the `UILabel` to a `UIImage` with a "printscreen" sort of function and then check the the pixels one by one (with for instance: [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)) and 'calculate' the left top en right bottom.

Comment: it's definitely not necessary to convert a label to an UIImage, the answer provided by Jeff Kelly is better. There are many attributes that can help you define the exact height of a UILabel

Comment: I disagree. For some fonts the height per capital (capHeight) differs per character (see http://bit.ly/OtdxOe). Other @properties of the `UIFont` class have the same 'problems'. I've had a similar problem when developing something in flash/as3. "Counting pixels" did it for me at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the text upwards by font.ascender - font.capHeight. Shrinking the height of a UILabel will likely clip its contents, so it is better to adjust the label's y position instead of resizing.

The following code sample explains the computation I used:

```
// in UILabel subclass:
- (CGFloat) topPadding
{
    // ascender = height from baseline to top of label (including top padding)
    // capHeight = height of a capital letter = ascender - top padding
    //  -> top padding = ascender - capHeight
    return self.font.ascender - self.font.capHeight;
}
```